# Even input() Python Closing Because Of Some Modules

Tags: python, module, operating-system, pynput

When i use pynput module in my code and start with python39.exe it closes automatically at the code which imports pynput. But in Visual Studio Code it has no problem. When I remove pynput module it starts working on python39.exe. Same happens when i declare path with os.path.join() function. I found nothing on Google. Please help me...

Comment: The major reason I can think of would be that Visual Studio is using a different virtual environment than you're using when interpreting the script outside of the IDE, Pynput is only installed in the VS environment, and the program is closing due to an `ImportError`. If you're double clicking the script to run it, open a `cmd` window and run it manually instead so that the window will stay open long enough for you to see the error. I'm guessing the error will be `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's correct. What should i do now ?

Comment: Install `pynput` using PIP in the cmd window instead of in the IDE, or switch to using the virtual environment that's used in VS.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for your help. I'm appreciated